# ggplot2: change strip.text position in facet_grid plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

you can set the position of the legend inside the plotting area, like

```
... + theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0))
```

Is there a similarly easy way to change the position of the strip text
(or factor levels in grouped plots)

```
library(reshape2); library(ggplot2)

sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex)

sp
```

[image]

(http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/)

in lattice I would use something like strip.text = levels(dat$Y)[panel.number()]
and panel.text(...), but there may be a cleaner way too...

thx, Christof

Comment: you could just use geom_text to add text wherever you want on your graph

Comment: MLavoie yes, thx, but how do I get the strip.text and the plot area ( in lattice something like panel.number() and current.panel.limits() ) ... I like to automate this and do not need it for this exact example, where I know the strip.text and the positions.

Comment: If you manualyl set `scale_x_continuous` limits, you can predict where text would fall, and based on number of characters you can compensate to adjust horizontal position.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
ggplot(tips, aes(x = total_bill, y = tip / total_bill)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sex), x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1.5, vjust = 1.5) +
  theme(
      strip.background = element_blank(),
            strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```

However, this is not moving the `strip.text`, rather, it's adding a `geom_text` element and turning off the `strip.background` and `strip.text`, but I think it achieves the desired outcome.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

A slight addition to @JasonAizkalns is to add the `check_overlap = T` option in `geom_text`, to avoid the superposition of multiple identical labels.

```
  ggplot(tips, aes(x = total_bill, y = tip / total_bill)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sex), x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1.5, vjust = 1.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +
  theme(
      strip.background = element_blank(),
            strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```